# Is it possible to detect an element without visible elements in CSS;

Tags: css

I have a div element nested buttons

```html
<div class="nav">
  <button>Home
  <button>Market
  <button>Profile
</div>
```

Ignoring the fact that I haven't closed the button tags in the source code is there any way to detect using CSS only whether all of the buttons are not visible so that I can restyle the div to fit the scenario (hide the div as it is useless in this case)

### Edit

By not visible I mean made invisible using styles like `display:none;` or `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: visible how ? off the screen ?

Comment: Not yet, soon CSS will have the `:has()` selector, but for now I don't think it's possible. You could refactor your CSS so that the div.nav doesn't have any padding, but instead the space comes from margin on the nav items. This way if there are no items *(`display: none`)* then the div.nav will be zero height and therefore basically be hidden

Comment: As @Simp4Code mentioned `:has()` selector is not compatible in many browsers!! but if you still want to use it. You can do that in chrome by enabling `#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` in `chrome://flags`